# How do you form the plural of an elided/contracted noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, contractions

The noun, without elision, is "beatings". Singular, elided, is "beatin'" (note the apostrophe). So what's the plural? I considered "beatins'" (note the apostrophe) and "beatin's" but neither of them seem correct.

Comment: When one is attempting to represent nonstandard speech in standard spellin'n punctuation, one makes it up as one goes along. They are, after all, not standard.

Comment: If I had to pick, I'd pick "*beatin's*", because the apostrophe indicates an omission, not a possession, and appears in the proper location of the omitted letter (as it does in *don't*), and because *s'* is only ever used for *possession* by a group or a proper noun ending in *s*, neither of which applies here.

Comment: @JordyDickinson, Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to pick, I'd pick "*beatin's*", because the apostrophe indicates an omission, not a possession, and appears in the proper location of the omitted letter (as it does in *don't*).

The only alternative, "*beatins'*", is inappropriate, because *s'* is only ever used for possession by a group or a proper noun ending in s, neither of which applies here.